# Scrapy reversed item ordening for preparing in db

Tags: python, scrapy

I am trying to put the items, scraped by my spider, in a mysql db via a mysql pipeline. Everything is working but i see some odd behaviour. I see that the filling of the database is not in the same order as the website itself. There is like a random order. Probably of the dictionary like list of the items scraped i guess.

My questions are:

1. how can i get the same order as the items of the website itself.
2. how can i reverse this order of question 1.

So items on website:

- A
- B
- C
- D
- E

adding order in my sql:

- E
- D
- C
- B
- A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items in a database are have not a special order if you don't impose it. So you should add a timestamp to your table in the database, keep it up-to-date (mysql has a special flag to mark a field as auto-now) and use ORDER BY in your queries.

Comment: Is possible of course but we are using the sequence of the mysql last in first out sequence. Would also be nice to know a solution for example if i would create a csv file with the same order as the website.

Comment: I think I have not understood the question... maybe you should clarify. Maybe some details on the query you are issuing would be useful.

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to say without the actual code, but in theory..

Scrapy is completely async, you cannot know the order of items that will be parsed and processed through the pipeline.

But, you can control the behavior by "marking" each item with `priority` key. Add a field `priority` to your `Item` class, in the `parse_item` method of your spider set the `priority` based on the position on a web page, then in your pipeline you can either write this `priority` field to the database (in order to have an ability to sort later), or gather all items in a class-wide list, and in `close_spider` method sort the list and bulk insert it into the database.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , its a good question . According to my understanding, Scrapy does a **Depth search** [more on depth search avaible here](https://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html?highlight=depth). So , when your crawling a website it does a depth search then automatically it changes the order of  contents you see in website and you scrape. I prefer you to use scrapy and make a **breadth search** , then i hope the way contents are arranged are not changed